# How can I add background scripts in manifest v3?

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am trying to convert manifest v2 to v3. I have updated everything instead of the background scripts that are giving error. I am using socket.io and popup js in background. It works fine in v2, but in v3 it gives error 'document is not defined' when I try to register it as service worker.

Here is the code for manifest v2:

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "description": "Testing",
    "version": "1.0",
    "host_permissions": [
        "*://*/*"
    ],
    "permissions":[
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "contextMenus",
        "offscreen",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "action": {
        "default_icon": "icons/icon32.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "32": "icons/icon32.png",
        "48": "icons/icon48.png",
        "128": "icons/icon128.png"
    },
    "background": {
        "service_worker":"service-worker.js",
        "type": "module"
    }
}
```

service-worker.js

```
import './socket.io.js';
import './popup.js';
```

I have tried with the following as well in service-worker.js, but it doesn't work as excepted

```
chrome.scripting
  .registerContentScripts([{
    id: "session-script",
    js: ["socket.io.js"],
    persistAcrossSessions: false,
    matches: ["*://example.com/*"],
    runAt: "document_start",
  }])
  .then(() => console.log("registration complete"))
  .catch((err) => console.warn("unexpected error", err))
```

Comment: The error is caused by a different problem: `document` means DOM, which is not present in a service worker by design. You need to do it inside the [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/).